# EVM precompile actions always returns error code -32603 when called

Tags: evm, frontier, precompile

We have started implementing a precompile for our NFT pallet but when I try testing it locally using Remix IDE when calling all of its actions I always get the following message:

```
Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
"code": -32603,
"message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert",
"data": "0x756e6b6e6f776e2073656c6563746f72"
}
```

with a different data parameter for each extrinsic. I am testing it using the latest MetaMask extension version and also tried to adjust the **gas limit** and **wei value** parameters but still get the same error. Any guidance on how to fix it?

P.S. You can find the precompile code [here](https://github.com/chexware/Bit-Country-Blockchain/tree/feature/nft-pallet-precompile) and the solidity interface contract [here](https://github.com/chexware/Bit-Country-Blockchain/blob/feature/nft-pallet-precompile/pallets/nft/NFTInterface.sol)

Comment: have you tried to interact via extrinsic? https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/access-evm-accounts/